# How to skip copying broken links with rsync --copy-links

Tags: rsync

This question taken almost verbatim from a [highly-voted comment-question](https://serverfault.com/questions/466651/force-rsync-to-copy-symlink-even-if-referent-does-not-exist#comment1142844_466666) at ServerFault which does not yet seem to have a decent answer on the web:

> I am using `rsync -L` to create copies of files instead of copying symlinks. Like `rsync -a -L` If a symlink points to missing file, `rsync` would fail with "symlink has no referent" error. Is there a way to skip copying broken symlinks when `-L` option set?

An idea?